# Does anyone actually use /æ/ as an emphatic article?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, dialects, sociophonetics

In the movie "Wayne's World" (1992), Mike Myers's character (the titular Wayne) says "I don't even own *æ* gun, let alone many guns that would necessitate an entire rack." To my ears (and to the ears of a phonetics/phonology prof who pointed this out to me), it definitely sounds like /æ/, but I can't find any documentation of a place/dialect that would pronounce it this way. Any help?
Here's the YouTube link for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJRvPmONjVY
and I found a little related discourse at this link, but it seems jumbled, to say the least: https://painintheenglish.com/case/5014
Related, and potentially useful info, is that I'm Midwestern (Chicago-born and Minnesota-raised), Mike Myers is Canadian, and "Wayne's World" takes place in Aurora, Illinois.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean /eI/ rather than /æ/?   English doesn't allow lone or final /æ/.  Sure enough, in all my years as a native English speaker, I haven't heard lone /æ/.  For those who came in late, /æ/ is the vowel sound in spoken "cat" and /eI/ is pronounced as /eI/.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann: If you listen to the YouTube clip he does actually say /æ/. I just found it part of the comedy. I don't think anybody actually would say it outside of similar wordplay.

Answer (score 3):

The vowel in question is (IPA) [a], not [æ]. The [æ]→[a] relation between US and Canadian English is common ([a] in Canada for US [æ]). Myers is just being weird: the article could be [ei] / [e] in parts of Canada and the US, or [ə] and not [æ,a] in any variety of North American English that I've encountered.

Comment: Doesn’t sound weird to me – using [a ~ æ] for the emphatic indefinite article is probably less common than [eɪ], but it’s common enough in my experience. Have definitely heard (and said) this myself many times.

Comment: Where does most of your experience come from? I didn't know that flapping could apply in American English before /n/, until I focused on a Texan colleagues otherwise unidentifiable dialect.

Comment: I’m afraid it’s a bit all over the place – a fairly random mix of UK and US, not tied down to any particular place. My own US accent is a fairly bland and nondescript Broadcast-ish amalgamation.